# Thymeleaf как присваивать значение полю boolean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, переменные, thymeleaf

Возможно вопрос является глупым, но для меня он таковым не оказался.
Проблема в том, что если я использую примитив `boolean` и добавляю в `modelAttribute` поле таким образом:

```
model.addAttribute("searchForTrailers", false);
```

И потом пытаюсь изменять его в представлении `Thymeleaf` таким образом:

```
<select th:object="${searchForTrailers}">
<option th:value="false">Машины</option>
<option th:value="true">Прицепы</option>            
</select>
```

То у меня выскакивает ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for boolean
```

А если я использую объект `Boolean` и кладу его таким образом:

```
model.addAttribute("searchForTrailers", Boolean.valueOf(false));
```

То получаю ту же самую ошибку.

Ведь насколько я понял для того, чтобы изменить значение, я по идее должен через `th:field` обратиться к полю этого объекта `Boolean`, ведь у `Boolean` по документации есть два поля-константы: `FALSE` и `TRUE`, и получается что я на стадии обращения уже должен знать какое значение должно быть выбрано и тогда весь смысл теряется.

Comment: А вы точно уверены в использовании атрибута `th:object` в `select`-теге вместо того, как он применяется обычным образом, а именно с атрибутом `th:field`? А если же ваша задача именно такова, то тогда можно инкапсулировать булево поле в какой-нибудь объект, передавать в форму как обычно пустой объект, а в `select` писать уже `th:field` на это самое его булево поле.

Comment: Нет, не уверен. В том то и дело, что я не знаю как правильно сделать. Про инкапсуляцию: я почти так и сделал: я переместил эту переменную на сторону Java кода в класс сущности, сделав ее статической, и теперь меняю ее на сторону Java кода. Так не очень хорошо вроде. Я уверен, что это костыль и правильней было бы делать это все-таки на стороне представления, но это хотя бы работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, я неправильно понял вашу логику использования этой булевой переменной, но тем не менее в комментарии я имел в виду решение, которое здесь опишу подробнее.

Создаём класс, который будет содержать булеву переменную:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class BooleanContainer {
    private Boolean bool;
}
```

*(lombok-аннотации могут быть заменены обычными конструкторами и геттерами-сеттерами)*

Затем в контроллере, выдающем ту страницу, на которой используется приведённый вами `select`, к модели добавим в числе прочих атрибутов и наш пустой объект-контейнер:

```
...
model.addAttribute("searchForTrailers", new BooleanContainer());
...
```

То есть, делаем мы это по аналогии с тем, как мы обычно передаём представлениям пустые объекты с целью затем получить их заполненными. Как, например, при какой-нибудь регистрации.

Тогда в коде выдаваемой html-страницы должна быть форма примерно такого вида:

```
<form th:object="${searchForTrailers}" th:action="@{/some/url}" method="post">
    <select th:field="*{bool}">
        <option th:value="false">Машины</option>
        <option th:value="true">Прицепы</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Затем когда пользователь выберет опцию и нажмёт на кнопку отправки, вы в том контроллере, который будет написан для обработки post-запроса по указанному URL-адресу, сможете достать выбранное булево поле у этого объекта. Готово.

И если это некая такая настроечная опция, то её может быть интересно сохранить в сессию, чтобы при следующих запросах действовал прежний выбор пользователя. При этом в сессию вы можете поместить как объект-контейнер, так и собственно значение его поля, так как, в принципе, только оно и интересует вроде.